# Hibernate Envers: "withModifiedFlag" is not set to 1 on INT column value changed to NULL

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have the `@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)` annotation on all the Entity properties which needs to be captured in my Audit table. It is working great for all the cases, except for value deletion. Meaning, If the value of my column is set from NULL/INT to some non-null value, then the corresponding `modifiedColumn` value is set to 1, But if the value is set from any INT value to NULL then the `modifiedColumn` is set to 0(indicates not modified). I have no clue why this is happening. I have checked in the Envers documents and also in the Envers open issues list and didn't find anything about it.

By the way, I use Hibernate & Hibernate-Envers 4.1.12.Final version.

**Update 1**

Here are my entity details:

```
@Entity
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
@AuditTable("AuditLatency")
public class Latency {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "DataCenter1")
    private Long dataCenter1;

    @Column(name = "DataCenter2")
    private Long dataCenter2;

    @Column(name = "DataCenter3")
    private Long dataCenter3;

    @Column(name = "StatusId")
    @Type(type = "enum_status_active_inactive_type")
    private Status statusId;

    //getXXX() & setXXX()

}
```

Audit Table result:
[image]

Pls notice that in each revision, even one of the column gets updated all other flags set to 1(true). And, for NULL values flag is set to 0.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: What version of Envers are you using?

Comment: I am using hibernate-envers-4.1.12.Final.jar

Comment: Can you include your entities and precisely how your code is modifying them?  I create a simple IntegerValueEntity with an Id and Integer value column and when I changed the value to null, the value_MOD field was 1 when running against 4.1.12.

Comment: @Naros - I have updated the quesion with entity information and the corresponding reference table values for reference.

Comment: Could you include the code where you modify your entity and commit it?  Perhaps there is something going strange there?  Are you using any other libraries that generate getter/setters, etc?

Comment: my getter/setters are implemented by me and they're simple. In my application I convert a DTO info into this Latency entity object and then call session.saveOrUpdate(entiy) method in my Dao.

Answer (score 0):

There must be awry with your scenario.

I used the following entity mapping and code on 4.1.12.Final and observed the modified flag was set correctly.

```
@Entity
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
public class IntegerValueEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;
  private Integer value;
  /* getter/setters */
}

@Test
public void runTest() {
    EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
    try {
        // revision 1, everything null
        SimpleEntity ive = new IntegerValueEntity();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist( ive );
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

        // revision 2, change value to non null
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        ive.setValue( 25 );
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

        // revision 3, change value to null
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        ive.setValue( null );
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

        final Boolean rev1 = getRevisionValueModifiedFlag( 1 );
        final Boolean rev2 = getRevisionValueModifiedFlag( 2 );
        final Boolean rev3 = getRevisionValueModifiedFlag( 3 );

        assertEquals( "Revision 1 should have been false", false, rev1 );
        assertEquals( "Revision 2 should have been true", true, rev2 );
        assertEquals( "Revision 3 should have been true", true, rev3 );
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {
        if ( entityManager.getTransaction().isActive() ) {
            entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        throw e;
    }
    finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

All `getRevisionValueModifiedFlag` does is executes a native query with the following:

```
SELECT value_MOD FROM IntegerValueEntity_AUD WHERE REV = :rev
```

If your entity is more complex or your business logic is more complex, once you share that information I'll update this answer accordingly.